# Calcular Valores de uma list

Tags: c#

Estou com um problema que é o seguinte: Eu tenho uma `list` que armazena os produtos de uma suposta locação em uma variável e inclui em uma tabela chamada `ItensReserva`. Eu preciso somar os valores desses itens para jogar no `textbox` que vai apresentar o valor total da locação, porém não estou conseguindo. Alguém pode me ajudar por favor? (Estou trabalhando com camadas)

Segue o código do botão:

```
private void simpleButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    if (CodigoReserva == 0)
    {
        reservaDto = new ReservaDTO();
    }
    reservaDto.Cliente = txtClienteReserva.Text;
    reservaDto.Ajustes = txtAjuste.Text;
    if (CodigoReserva == 0)
    {
        List<ItensReservaDto> itensReserva = new List<ItensReservaDto>();
        foreach (ProdutoDTO produto in Produtos)
        {
            var itensReservaDto = new ItensReservaDto();
            itensReservaDto.CodigoProduto = produto.Id;
            itensReservaDto.ValorProduto = produto.Preco;
            itensReserva.Add(itensReservaDto);
        }

        reservaDto.ItensReserva = itensReserva;

        bll.inserir(reservaDto);


    }
    else
    {
        List<ItensReservaDto> itensReserva = new List<ItensReservaDto>();
        foreach (ProdutoDTO produto in Produtos)
        {
            if(produto.ItensReserva == null)
            {
                var itensReservaDto = new ItensReservaDto();
                itensReservaDto.CodigoProduto = produto.Id;
                itensReservaDto.ValorProduto = produto.Preco;
                itensReserva.Add(itensReservaDto);
            }
        }
        reservaDto.ItensReserva = itensReserva;
        reservaDto.ItensReservaExcluidos = itensReservaExcluidos;
        reservaDto.Cliente = txtClienteReserva.Text;
        reservaDto.Ajustes = txtAjuste.Text;
        bll.update(reservaDto);

    } 
    this.Close();

}
private void Reserva_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //DateTime data = DateTime.Now;
    //mkreserva.Text = data.Date.ToString();        

    if (CodigoReserva > 0)
    {
        reservaDto = bll.pegarReserva(CodigoReserva);
        txtAjuste.Text = reservaDto.Ajustes;
        txtClienteReserva.Text = reservaDto.Cliente;
        txtvalortotal.Text = reservaDto.ValorTotal.ToString();

        ProdutoBLL produtoBll = new ProdutoBLL();
        Produtos.Clear();
        foreach (var itemReserva in reservaDto.ItensReserva)
        {
            ProdutoDTO produto = produtoBll.pegarProduto(itemReserva.CodigoProduto);
            Produtos.Add(produto);
            produto.ItensReserva = itemReserva;
        }
    }
}
```

Segue o método `inserir`:

```
public void inserir(ReservaDTO dto)
{
    bd.Conectar();

string comando = "INSERT INTO reserva(Cliente,Data_Reserva,Data_Retirada,  Data_Prova, Ajustes ,ValorTotal) Values ('" + dto.Cliente + "','" + dto.DataReserva + "','" + dto.DataRetirada + "','" + dto.DataProva + "','" + dto.Ajustes + "','" + dto.ValorTotal + "')";
    var codigo = bd.ExecutarComandoSql(comando);

    var itensProdutoBll = new ItensReservaBll();

    for (int i = 0; i < dto.ItensReserva.Count; i++)
    {
        var itensReserva = dto.ItensReserva[i];
        itensReserva.CodigoReserva = int.Parse(codigo.ToString());
        itensProdutoBll.inserir(itensReserva);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Se bem entendi, você só precisa usar o `Sum` do LINQ.

```
var soma = itensReserva.Sum(item => item.ValorProduto);
```